# Syntax error when using string concatenation in function argument

Tags: php, php-5.5

Using php 5.5.38.

Simple script:

```
<?php

function a ($a = 'XXX' . 'TTT') {
    echo 'Hello ' . $a;
}


a();
```

This fails with:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in line 3

Does php 5.5 not support concatenation in there?

Comment: You can't have expressions inside the function default parameters, only primitive values.

Comment: @Phiter You mean at all or just in php 5.5?

Comment: I believe just in 5.5. Look https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Comment: It works on 7.1 https://ideone.com/zdpGok

Comment: fml. Thanks @Phiter.

Comment: @Phiter It also work on 5.6

Comment: It was added in PHP 5.6 - see the section at the top of the changelog labelled [Constant Expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)

Comment: @iainn I was about to send that link! haha https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs

Comment: You can see how it reacts in different versions at https://3v4l.org/7F69F

Comment: One more thing. I have similar error when I define a class property as `public $val = 3 * 2; ` It gives syntax error on asterix. Same reason perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was added in PHP 5.6. The same rule applies to class propety declarations.

> It is now possible to provide a scalar expression involving numeric
>   and string literals and/or constants in contexts where PHP previously
>   expected a static value, such as constant and property declarations
>   and default function arguments.

See: [Constant expressions](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs)

Answer (score 0):

It seams like in PHP 7 you can use string concatenation in the function argument defaults, but it doesn't make any sence.

Answer (score 0):

no php 5.5.38. does not support this method. You need a php version that is >= 5.6.0

Good luck